# Database design for multiple user preferences?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am designing a database for a dating site which requires a user to select partner preferences, which in turn drives the matching process. Essentially, what I want is the user to be able to set single or multiple options for each preference. For example, Partner Location could be NY only or NY, Boston, Miami, LA and so forth. I wanted to know if the idea I have in mind is the preferred way of doing things.

This is what I was thinking of doing.

```
Users Table |    User_Options Table    |    Options Table    | Preferences Table
            |                          |                     |           
ID | Name   | ID | User_id | Option_ID | ID | Name | Pref_id | ID | Name 
1. | John   | 1. |  1.     |   1.      | 1. |  NY  |   1     | 1. | Location
            |                          |                     |
```

This way each has many options and each option has many users. I have linked the options table to preferences so that I can hopefully call a user based on the preference category. I was hoping `user.location` or something along those lines would give me all the location options selected by the user. My preferences table is going to include religion, location, diet, drinking habit etc. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This is not a simple question. And it can prove to be quite complex for mysql if the project grows pretty big. Depending on what you think you will have later, maybe it is a good ideea to look through graph databases, which are specialized in this kind of thing. One example would be [Neo4J](http://www.neo4j.org/?utm_expid=2722339-1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F).

Comment: I intrigued. FYI, I am a complete newbie to development and I am using rails to develop my app. I don't mind the challenge of learning to work with graph databases as I not faced by time constraints. I'd rather do things the right way. I want to know though if Neo4J can be (easily) implemented with rails or if there are any alternatives?

Comment: I have been working with neo4j but in php, using it for linking users together in a online store based on their buying habbits so we can send specialized newsletters for every group of users. And it's been working fine for us. We have differend conditions for our users than what you have, but the applicability seems to be quite similar, that's why I recommended it. While it's a new concept, it proved to be a very efficient one for us, allowing us to get rid of some very expensive mysql queries. As for ease of use, Neo4j uses a rest api for easy access.

Comment: I would at least read about it a little, and decide wether is a good solution for your problem :)

Comment: I would somehow want to use it with Postgres so I can still use Devise and other gems that are dependent on ActiveRecord and not up to date for neo4j. I think the main part of the app is to be able to exclusively match members solely based on partner preferences. But I have absolutely no clue about how to go about it so need to put in a some hours/days of research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your explanation I would suggest splitting two entities, i.e.: preferences and locations. If you'll include location in preferences table you propably will need flag column that marks or this preference is location or is not. I'm assuming that system should find matches that have got the same preferences i.e. hobbys, religion **AND** live in desirable area, not got the same preferences **OR** live in some area. Therefore I suggest slightly changed schema.

[image]

Then you can simply query about matches in some particulat location prefered by another user and with preferences chosen by him (if we are looking for matches for user with user_id 1 following his/hers favoured locations and preferences):

```
select r.user_id
from
(select uu.user_id from users u
right join user_location ul using (user_id)
right join users uu on uu.location_id = ul.location_id
where u.user_id = 1) r
inner join user_preference up on up.user_id = r.user_id
inner join user_preference up1 on up1.preference_id = up.preference_id and 
       up1.user_id = 1
group by r.user_id;
```

Another issue: if you are using junction table like User_Options in your examole - there is no need of creating artificial key. Composite primary key (user_id and option_id) will be much more justified in this case. (look at 2 junction tables in my example - user_locations and user_preferences).

Comment: I'm a little confused by this to be completely honest with you. The Preferences table in my example is more a less a categories table. It provides a label to the option selected. What I imagined was including all the possible options that the user can select in the options table. So the Options table would have things like [New York, Boston, all other cities, Muslim, Christian, all other religions, vegetarian, non-vegetarian, vegan and so forth]

Comment: and the way to identify which category they belong to i would pass in a preference_id column which would indicate that New York, Boston etc have preference Id 1 which is Location. Christian, Muslim etc have preference Id 2 which is religion in the preferences table. Just want to make sure we are on the same page. The graph is slightly confusing for a novice like me because I can't figure out the has_many, has_one, belongs_to relationships. Could you please provide some feedback based on this?

Comment: sure, your approach will be ok as long as you don't have to use location for any other purposes, i.e. address for correspondence, supplier's address, place when some event's address. Then you'll have to create other table - addresses with the same data you already have in your option-preferences structure. In this case that would be volating of 1NF.

Comment: On other hand imagine how do you want to querying about the preferences and locations? Wanna keep 'locations' tag as a string in a code? or like I mentioned before: location is not more important as a hobby? I mean if you are looking for match then hobby is not more important than location (or and and question above)?

Comment: I do have a location column in the users table for the users current location. Would that cause any issues?

Comment: and how do you wanna to query about user location using your previous design?

Comment: well I have a Profile model that belongs to Users. So I can do this. user.profile.location whereas for the preferences part I was hoping to join tables and come up with something like "user.location" which would give me all the cities the user wants his partner to be from. Make any sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21958/discussion-between-borys-and-pratski)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of looking at this from a [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) perspective first. It's a fairly in depth subject, but over all, you want to model the key concepts and ensure that the code you will be writing is sound. This assumes that you are planning on approaching this problem in an object oriented fashion.

If you think of your project in terms of objects that have state and behaviour, you'll (hopefully) end up with more robust code that can handle changes better.

In terms of entities, I'd start by defining the "user" and their personal attributes ("name", "religion", "location").

I'd then take a long look at each of the preferences that you plan on using to generate a "match". You'll probably find a lot of things missing that you'll want to consider adding to the model (i.e. for "location" is that a set lat/long and radius or a set of zip codes).

My feeling is that initially going generic in terms of the options and preferences is going to backfire. You need to define at least a handful of these and see what's common and promote the commonalities into a parent class or interface.

For data persistence, keep a separation of responsibilities in your code. Your entities should not be responsible for saving themselves. You should create other objects that map your entities to whatever database (document, whatever) structure you choose. This will let you change the underlying persistence layer without directly impacting the functionality of your site. An example for say PHP would be the [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Lastly, get comfortable with unit testing. You don't mention your implementation language so here's a [list of unit test frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks) that you use as a reference.

I know that this doesn't directly answer your question so to give you a slightly more on topic answer;

- keep your database normalized (unless you *need* to denormalize for performance)
- use foreign keys to maintain referential integrity
- refactor your database structure as and when you need to